# 3D Orthographic Projection

Tags: opengl, orthographic

I want to construct a Orthographic projection to make my sun's shadow map look right. Unfortunately, the code is not achieving the desired results as using the regular perspective projection. Here's my code for setting up the projection matrix:

```
glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)shadowMap.x, (GLsizei)shadowMap.y);
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

//suns use this
glOrtho(0, shadowMap.x, 0, shadowMap.y, 0.1,1000.0);

glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

From what I understand that should be correct. However, after a quick debug render, I noticed that the scene was rendering in a tiny portion of the screen. After some experimentation, I found changing the shadowMap values in glOrtho made it cover the whole texture, but  it was really zoomed in. In my perspective projection I use 0.1 and 1000.0 for my near and far, and I've experimented with those and it does change the results, but not get the desired results still. The only time that I get the correct results is when the values are kept with shadowMap.x and shadowMap.y, but like I said, its rendering really small.

What am I doing wrong here? Everything I've read said that the initial code is correct.

EDIT:
Apparently it wasn't clear that this is for the shadow map pass, the regular pass is rendered with perspective and is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow mapping is multi pass algorithm.
You are reffering to the first pass (point 1).

1. Render scene form light source view into depth texture
2. Render scene from camera view with depth texture projection mapping enabled.

   - current fragment xy+depth is then transformed into light projection coordinates and is compared to stored depth on depth texture
   - if both depths are equal (or nearly equal) current fragment should be considered as lit, otherwise as shadowed.

So everything's fine with your code, store depth values from this pass to depth texture and proceed to point 2.

One thing you should think about is how wide area your light should cover (in world space). With loadidentity on modelview you are attempting to cover 1 world unit x 1 world unit area for you light only.

- Consider we have a sphere at 0,0,0 with radius 5.0
- We have depth texture of 256,256 dims.
- We want to project it along Z onto sphere.

  glVieport(0,0,256,256);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadidentity();
  glOrtho(-2.5,2.5,-2.5,2.5,-1000,1000);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadidentity();
  //flip z, we cast light from obove
  glRotate(1,0,0,180);

Comment: I know how shadow mapping works, this is the code for the projection for the light source. I guess that wasn't made clear in the question, updated. Also, you're wrong that this code is correct because either pass, the scene would still be rendering at the wrong projection, so technically this is shadow map independent.

Comment: Updated final note :)

Comment: I don't know if your final not is orthographic specific, because I've never looked into it, but further in the rendering the geometry is translated into camera space. Because orthographic projection doesn't use transformations, should I omit the camera translation from the model view?

Comment: Ortho will scale -1 +1 square to your depth texture, this is ok. But you need to scale modelview matrix in order to fit your world onto this projection. If you dont your texture will contain only -1 +1 square.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you set the light modelview matrix. You can render a shadow map using the code below:

```
double* getOrthoMVPmatrix(vector3 position,vector3 lookat,
                          GLdouble  left,  GLdouble  right,
                          GLdouble  bottom,  GLdouble  top,
                          GLdouble  nearVal,  GLdouble  farVal)
{

 glPushMatrix();

 double projection[16];
 double modelView[16];
 double *matrix = new double [16];

 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glOrtho(  left, right, bottom, top, nearVal,  farVal) ;
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(position.x,position.y,position.z,lookat.x,lookat.y,lookat.z,0,1,0);

 glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelView);
 glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);


 glPopMatrix();

 matrix  = projection*modelView;

 return matrix ;

}


void renderShadowMap(void)
{

 //"Bind your depth framebuffer"

 glViewport(0,0,"Your SM SIZE","Your SM SIZE");
 glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
 glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 double *MVP =  getOrthoMVPmatrix( "your light position","your light position" + "your light direction",
                          -"left","right",
                           "bottom","top",
                           "near","far"
                          ) ;


 //"call glUseProgram to bind your shader"

 // set the uniform MVP we made "

 //"Draw your scene "

 glViewport(0,0,"screen width","screen height");


}
```

Your will need to make a multiplication operator for double [16] array. In my case i made a matrix class but do it your way.
Dont forget to call glCullFace(GL_BACK) before drawing your real scene and free MVP after.

Comment: The problem is not in how I render the shadow map, its how I make the ortho projection.